# Cannot resolve taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() in android firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

This is my code to upload image to firebase storage. it works well. but I cannot get download url after upload

```
        ref.putFile(uri)
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        URL url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl()
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    }
                });
```

In firebase 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1', it cannot resolve getDownloadUrl().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this implementation. Use `continueWithTask` to get the downloaded url.

```
final UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(uri);   
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                                        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    throw task.getException();

                                                }
                                                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                                                return filepath.getDownloadUrl();

                                            }
                                        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                    thumb_download_url = task.getResult().toString();


                                                }
                                            }
                                        });

                                    }
                                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: Good answer! It works well in my side. I could get correct url using task.getResult().toString(); from onComplete Method.

Answer (score 1):

```
Task<Uri> urlTask = ref.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();

    }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                // Downloadable uri

            } else {
                 // Handle failures
            }
       }
});
```

Comment: I hope this will help.

Comment: Do you have complete project github url?

Comment: Complete project of what ?

Comment: I mean, do you have sample project using above code? or is there any github url?

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/storage. Refer MyUploadService.java